# How to auto set the textbox based on dropdown selection?

Tags: php, codeigniter, dropdown

How to auto set the textbox based on dropdown selection? I have a dropdown for position and textbox for department. What I would like to do is when "Guidance Faculty" is selected from dropdown, the textbox will automatically set to "Guidance" and it will become readonly and same in when "OSA Faculty" is selected from dropdown, the textbox will automatically set to "OSA" and it will become readonly. While if "Department Chair" and "Professor" is selected nothing will happen to textbox or it will set to "".

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="position">Position</label>
        <?php
            echo form_open('signup');
            $options = array(
                '' => 'Select Position',
                'Department Chair' => 'Department Chair',
                'Professor' => 'Professor',
                'Guidance Faculty' => 'Guidance Faculty',
                'OSA Faculty' => 'OSA Faculty',
            );
            echo "<div class='drop_pos'>";
            echo form_dropdown('position', $options, 'class="btn dropdown-toggle"', 'data-toggle="dropdown-menu"');
        ?>
        <div class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('position');?></div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="department">Department</label>
         <input class="form-control" name="department" placeholder="Department" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('Department');?>"/>
         <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('department');?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try something to achieve your goal? You can play with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="position">Position</label>
        <?php
            echo form_open('signup');
            $options = array(
                '' => 'Select Position',
                'Department Chair' => 'Department Chair',
                'Professor' => 'Professor',
                'Guidance Faculty' => 'Guidance Faculty',
                'OSA Faculty' => 'OSA Faculty',
            );
            echo "<div class='drop_pos'>";
            echo form_dropdown('position', $options, 'class="btn dropdown-toggle"', 'data-toggle="dropdown-menu" onChange="javascript:document.getElementsByName(\'department\').value=this.value;"');
        ?>
        <div class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('position');?></div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="department">Department</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="department" placeholder="Department" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('Department');?>"/>
    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('department');?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: you can inspect, see the console & write the output so I can help

Comment: I don't know how to use console in inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `JS` like below.

First set dropdown box like this...

```
echo form_dropdown('position', $options, array('id'=>'pos','class'=>'btn dropdown-toggle','data-toggle'=>'dropdown-menu','onchange'=>'changefuc();'));
```

Then add **JS**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function changefuc(){
    var pos = document.querySelector('#pos');
    var dept = document.querySelector('[name="department"]'); 
    pos.addEventListener('change',function(){
      dept.value = this.value;
    });
  }
  </script>
```

**UPDATE**

See demo

```js
    var pos = document.querySelector('#pos');
    var dept = document.querySelector('[name="department"]'); 
    pos.addEventListener('change',function(){
      dept.value = this.value;
    });
```

```html
<select id="pos">
 <option value="" selected >Select Position</option>
 <option value="Department Chair">Department Chair</option>
 <option value="Professor">Professor</option>
 <option value="Guidance Faculty">Guidance Faculty</option>
 <option value="OSA Faculty">OSA Faculty</option>
</select>
<input class="form-control" name="department" placeholder="Department" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Nothing happens.

Comment: I don't know how to use console in inspect element.

Comment: just fress `F12` then see on `console` tab.

Comment: did you load `form` helper first to use `form_dropdown`?if not load it first.

Comment: see demo in edited code. try exactly like this..it Works

Answer (score 0):

in jquery something like this:

```
jQuery("select[name='position']").on("change", function() {

   // value of selected option
   var selectedPosition = $(this).val();

   if (selectedPosition) {
       // the inputbox
       jQuery("input[name='department']").val(selectedPosition).attr('readonly', true);
   } else {
       jQuery("input[name='department']").val('').attr('readonly', false);
   }

});
```